# ST_Dump and "geometry dump" error

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.3

I am trying to dump a set of point/multipoint rows with this query:

```
   SELECT a.gid, a.nid, a.uid, a.cod_reg, postgis.st_dump(geom)
   FROM table a
```

but I get this error

> ERROR:  relation "geometry_dump" does not exist

PostgreSQL 9.6 running on Debian/Linux and 
Postgis 2.3

Same query works on another server with PostgreSQL 9.2 running on Debian/Linux and Postgis 2.0

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have installed the PostGIS extension in the `postgis` schema in your DB (default is `public`).

Since you get an error for a sub-function, it means that the PostGIS extension looks at the wrong place to find all required functions. To solve this, make sure the user running this command has the `postgis` schema in its search path. You can read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407622/postgis-not-available-for-all-postgres-users/48422325#48422325) for more details

```
SET search_path TO "$user", public, postgis;
```

Comment: I've already set search_path to postgis schema, no success (with new login)

Comment: According to https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_dump.html geometry_dump is a datatype that's what I miss... (still don't know why)

Comment: @rmorelli74 it is the data type returned by st_dump. If it can't be found, it will fail (and if there is no postgis specific returned data type, it would fail at the first postgis function)

Comment: after digging into privileges and moving back postgis extension to public schema I've found that "public" schema was not in my search path as regular user (thought with superuser privileges)... my fault. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you also installed in both cases postgis extension in your database with `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`?

You may look at [the doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) as no `postgis.st_dump` exists.

You should do instead

```
SELECT a.gid, a.nid, a.uid, a.cod_reg, st_dump(geom)
   FROM table a
```

to solve your issue